# XCode custom template - folder structure for only a checkbox (where to put variation "checkbox not ticked")?

Tags: xcode, templates

I followed this tutorial "[Advanced Xcode 9 File Template](http://jeanetienne.net/2017/09/10/advanced-xcode-template.html)" to create a more advanced template for XCode. It is explained that you need to create a folder with a specific name for every option variation there is. In the tutorial, there was a dropdown menu and a checkbox.

But what if I only have a checkbox? Following the tutorial, I'd need to create a folder without a name. That's not possible. Thus, I tried it without a folder for that variation (the checkbox identifier is `CreateModelAttributeInSection`):
[image]

When I uncheck the checkbox though, there are no files being generated. It works when I do check the checkbox, however.

What folder do I need to create for the variation "checkbox not ticked"? I can't find a solution.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After diving in to the default Xcode templates I found one of theirs that also just used a single checkbox, which is the C file template:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates/Source/C\ File.xctemplate
```

Looking at their structure, with nothing selected it reads the template files from the `Default` directory. With the checkbox checked it'll read from the directory named the same as the `Identifier` value of the checkbox option.